# Facebook like button sharing wrong link

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the same iframe like button in 2 different pages, the only variation is the file name:

In this page the button works and shares how-openstack.aspx successfully.
http://www.dualtec.com.br/dualtec/webinar/how-openstack-mensagem.aspx

But in this page the button doesn't share the right link, dualstack-handson.aspx
http://www.dualtec.com.br/dualtec/webinar/dualstack-handson-mensagem.aspx

Any idea?

Comment: Which button on page are you referring to?

Comment: The Facebook like button. Thanks